# How to access the contents of a cell in HTML table using the cell id?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a table in HTML using JavaScript functions insertRow() and insertCell() functions. I have assigned an id for each cell. I would like to get the value/content of the cell in JavaScript.

Following is the code used to create the table:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            row.id = rowCount;

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.id = rowCount + 'a';
            cell1.innerHTML = "CELL1";

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.id = rowCount + 'b';
            cell2.innerHTML = "CELL2";

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell3.id = rowCount + 'c';
            cell3.innerHTML = "CELL3";

            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell4.id = rowCount + 'd';
            cell4.innerHTML = "CELL4";
        }
     </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <thead>
    <TD>Column 1</TD>
    <TD>Column 2</TD>
    <TD>Column 3</TD>
    <TD>Column 4</TD>
    </thead>
    </TABLE>

</BODY>
```

I have already tried out the following options:

1. alert(document.getElementById(1a));
   Null
2. alert(document.getElementById(1a).value);
   Error message: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined
3. alert(document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[rowCount].cells[0]);
   [Object]
4. alert(document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[rowCount].cells[0].toString());
   [Object]
5. alert(document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[rowCount].cells[0].value);
   undefined

Comment: `document.getElementById('1a')` should work?

Comment: Hi Brad, I have already tried that. When i try to alert it, I am getting a null.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you get the cell's value.

Given you name them serially (starting with row then a,b,c,d you should be able to access them by id as `1a` or `3c`. With that said, the following [is working](http://jsfiddle.net/6KJxb/) (supplemental to what you've posted):

```
<!-- head -->
<script>
    function getVal(cellId){
        var cell = document.getElementById(cellId);
        document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = cell.innerHTML;

        // highlight the cell for visual effect
        cell.className = 'target';
        setTimeout(function(){ cell.className = ''; }, 1e3);
    }
</script>
<!-- /head -->

<!-- body -->
<INPUT type="text" id="q" />
<INPUT type="button" value="Get Value" onclick="getVal(document.getElementById('q').value);" />
<span id="a"></span>
<!-- /body -->
```

Comment: I am getting the following error message: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined

Comment: Is that on the jsFiddle?  make sure to enter a valid ID; I didn't add any error checking in that snippet as it's just a proof-of-concept (and you'd need to add a row before trying to look-up).

Comment: No it is not on the jsFiddle.. and I am getting the error with the the following line in the code highlighted: "document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = cell.innerHTML;" Moreover I too fail to understand this line, since there is no element with it's ID as "a".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should know the row number.

Use document.getElementById(id) to get the content. For example, id = $rownumber + [abcd]

Answer (score 0):

Table cells have no `value` attribute, but you can access the content via the `innerHTML` property or the `innerText` property. The differences are that the latter has somewhat more limited browser support and it gives the text content, without any tags. Example:

```
alert(document.getElementById('1a').innerHTML)
```

If this does not work (as a comment seems to say), then the problem is somewhere else. Then you should post code that actually reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To access the contents of the cells with your current code you only have to address each cell by the id you gave it, then access the innerHTML atribute:

```
    var myCell = document.getElementById('1c')

    var myCellContent = myCell.innerHTML
```

Remember that you have the heading for each column, so your first row that actually has content will be the '1' and not the '0'.

Comment: For some reason, I am getting the following error while trying out this one too. Error message: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined"

Comment: You must be have some part of your code where you are still addressing the "value" property (maybe when you where trying to get it to work) because it's not on any part of the code you have posted. Look for that and try again =)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to access the cell contents using the following piece of code:

**document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[rowCount].cells[0].innerHTML**